# Creating custom test rule for spock

Tags: junit, spock

I am using Spock to testing with groovy and I want a custom test rule on fail. First i did that with MethodRule which is deprecated now. So I tried TestWacher but Spock caches Exceptions before my rule can cache it.

```
    public class SimpleOnFailed extends TestWatcher {

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        print "Prints when test fails"
    }

}
```

and it never prints my print statement from failed method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue with Spock and `TestRule`s throwing exceptions that's not easy to fix because Spock's semantics differ from JUnit's in this regard. (If you are interested in the details, you can find out more at http://forum.spockframework.org.) Solutions are to use a `MethodRule` instead (which is no longer deprecated in latest JUnit) or write a Spock extension. The latter isn't yet considered a stable SPI, but if you can live with potential changes, have a look at the extensions in the Spock codebase (http://github.spockframework.org).

Comment: Thanks for answering, so I am going to stick with `MethodRule`